# Erro para abrir pacotes no R

Tags: r, plot, atualização

Estou com problema para rodar as funções no meu RStudio. Sempre aparece essa mensagem de erro quando vou rodar o Plotly ou sjPlot

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sjPlot’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): namespace ‘cli’ 3.3.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.4.0 is required
```

Minha versão do R é a 4.2, já atualizei todos os pacotes, já desinstalei e instalei de novo. Não sei o que fazer mais. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Veja esta parte do erro: `namespace ‘cli’ 3.3.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.4.0 `. Descarregue o `cli` com `detach("package:cli", unload=TRUE)`. E carregue ele novamente: `library(cli)` Verifique a versão: `packageVersion("cli")`

Comment: Aparece a seguinte mensagem: Error in detach("cli", unload = TRUE) : argumento 'name' inválido

Comment: Tem certeza que está instalado? `system.file(package='cli')`

Comment: O RStudio carrega uma série de pacotes, incluindo o pacote `cli`. Uma maneira segura e que evita andar à procura de soluções que funcionem é fechar o RStudio, abrir uma janela de prompt de comando e correr `R -q -e "install.packages('cli')"`. Funciona em todos os sistemas operacionais.